# Spring, JPA, Mysql LOAD DATA INFILE could not serialize

Tags: java, mysql, serialization, spring-data-jpa, load-data-infile

I'm using JPA to load info from a CSV to MySQL, here the query:

```
@Query(value = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :file INTO TABLE info FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' (d_create, folder, work, status, country, component, type)", nativeQuery = true)
void upldInf(@Param("file")MultipartFile file);
```

It works.. or at least it's suppoused, because the catch gets the next excepion:
    `could not serialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize`, and the data isn't loaded to MySQL.

Does anyone know why or what about the exception?
Thanks in advance for your comments and help!